# unable to connect to chromedriver http://127.0.0.1:9515 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I have installed chrome-driver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
and I have installed both Google-chrome browser also.
I want to Run cucumber test cases using chrome browser instead of Firefox browser but I am stuck with this error.
Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: add 127.0.0.1, *local, localhost in the bypass section under Settings > Network(proxy) > advanced

Comment: On which OS are you on ?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.10 OS.

Comment: @PrashanthSams - I have tried to change proxy setting as you mentioned but still Its not working for me. I have uninstalled browser, chrome-driver and clear the case as well.
Now I have res-installed it properly but still its now working and getting same error again an again unable to connect to chromedriver http://127.0.0.1:9515 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)

Comment: @DevendraBobde I am also working on the same profile that you are handling right now. Rails-Ruby-cucumber-selenium-capybara | Generally Chrome is working for me. Also am new to capybara-cucubmer stuffs; just doing POC for my new client; can you please share any sample project so that I can better understand the concepts. Please let me know so that I can share my email id or skype

Comment: @PrashanthSams - Thanks for your reply, I will share it. About this issue I am facing this on my machine, The same thing I did on someone's machine ITs working fine It didnt throw any exception at all.
So, I am wondering Why its not working on my machine?

Comment: @DevendraBobde I already documented this in my machine to work with Chrome browser; Just now I saw :) It will work

Answer (score 21):

I had this issue because of path override with rbenv shim. 
It's worth checking where `which chromedriver` points too.

For me the fix was:
`gem uninstall chromedriver-helper` and `brew install chromedriver`

Comment: the `chromedriver-helper` gem messed up my system too :-)

Comment: The `chromedriver-helper` gem was mysteriously installed on my system to. It turns out it is in the default Gemfile in new versions of rails, and I installed a fresh rails app to play around. All the tests in my 4.2 app broke. Took forever and a vagrant destroy to track it down.

Comment: Thank you. In my case when I ran `gem uninstall chromedriver-helper` I saw "Remove executables: chromedriver in addition to gem?" message and said yes

Answer (score 5):

If you using rbenv on linux machine then

copy 'chromedriver' to current using ruby versions like below -

cp chromedriver  $HOME/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin

Example: cp chromedriver  home/abc_user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin

and then set the permissions like -

chmod +x home/abc_user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/chromedriver

Comment: I followed another way - just found where gems installed binaries for chromedriver and deleted the binaries. Then installed chromedriver via brew. In my case I run the following commands: `rm /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.2.4/bin/chromedriver` and `rm /usr/local/opt/rbenv/shims/chromedriver`

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal:
brew link --overwrite chromedriver

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered after installation of ansicon1.60 for colourful screen. After uninstalling it by the following command in ansicon directory:

`C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\x64>ansicon.exe -i`

after that, i decided not to use ansicon.

Answer (score 1):

If you have rbenv concerns problem, you may try:

```
$ rbenv rehash
```

and then run your test again. ;)

Answer (score 0):

## ChromeDriver setup in Linux [Ubuntu]

Open Terminal and download Chromedriver using the cmd

> $ wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.7/chromedriver_linux64.zip
>
> $ Unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
>
> $ cp chromedriver /usr/local/bin
>
> $ chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

Comment: I have tried this But still its not working.
I am getting this error -   unable to connect to chromedriver http://127.0.0.1:9515 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use ansicon1.60 for colourful screen.

Run cmd /d which starts the command prompt without processing its AutoRun entry, thus bypassing ANSICON. Then you should just be able to do \x64\ansicon -u.